# How can we provide the access for running chat ie Chat supervisior in live agent

Tags: liveagent

while agent and user are chatting in live agent ,another user should access and see the chat,we have configured the live agent and we need a user to access the running chat

Answer (score 1):

You only mention "live agent", but it's just exposing a tab in either Classic or Lightning.

In *Classic*, this is called [Supervisor Panel](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_access_supervisor_panel.htm&type=5).

In *Lightning*, this is called [Omni-Channel Supervisor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_supervisor_intro.htm&type=5)

> Use Omni-Channel Supervisor to monitor agent workloads and the status of work items that are routed by Omni-Channel. Agents can raise flags on work items when they require assistance from a supervisor. Supervisors can monitor conversations between agents and customers, and send helpful messages that only the support agent sees.

**You can add either of these tabs to the Navigation items in a console app** (if the supervisors have their own app) as mentioned in this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/omni-channel-lex/omni-supervisor). Otherwise, you can create a permission set to expose the tab for Omni Supervisor (object) and assign to the relevant users.

[image]
[image]